# How to connect Android from PC via MTP in command line?

Tags: android, linux, mtp

I am trying to implement a program on PC which will retrive pcitures from like 100 Android phones all pluged in.

However after running some test, I already found out on Ubuntu it can automatically mount up 40 phones, others can be recognized on the bus but cannot be mounted automatically.

So I am trying to find out a way to connect MTP device in ubuntu command line.

So far I tried mtpfs from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702&page=8)
using "mtpfs -o allow_other /media/mtp/" seems it is still automatically finding available devices and mount them to mountpoint.
this is not what Im looking for, I hope it can be done like mounting an disk by mount/umount.
is that possible?

Comment: It's unclear what you are looking for specifically, or what you have tried. If you can provide your code so far, people can suggest how to add functionality, but this question has too little detail for others to help you effectively.

Comment: Thanks David , I am not an english speaker, it is hard for me to keep my question organised. I edited my quetion ,try to make it more detailed.